# Developing Basic Google Glass App

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm making a basic Google Glass app that will take some data from the user (i.e. name, date), and then basically run an algorithm prompting the user to do something (i.e. check a patient) every 5 minutes. I've been having some trouble with the structure and developing in general so far. When the app is launched, there's a card that says to "Enter info." How can I prompt the user to input data like the date? And should each one of these data requests be separate activities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use voice, you can follow [this sample code](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#starting_speech_recognition).

You could add a prompt on the screen so the user knows what to input:
`intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, <message you want to display>);`

This will give you the text in the form of a String.

Otherwise, you can create a TextView in your activity that is updated by an event such as `onScroll()`.